# dynamically added elements with absolute positioning do not flow with parent

Tags: javascript, css

I am playing around with JavaScript. I am having an issue with page resizing and the position of dynamically created elements. The Parent div is positioned relative and the appended child elements are absolute in relation to the parent they are added to. When I shrink the browser window the parent scales ok but the children's positions do not get updated. How would you handle a situation like this in the real world?
Thanks
PS: keep in mind I am trying to learn this and a lot I'm sure is wrong or unnecessary. I appreciate the correction as well.

```html
    <html>
    <head>
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="1.css"> -->
    <script language="javascript"></script>
    <style>
    #div1{
    postion:relative;
    margin:auto auto;
    height:400px;
    width:400px;
    background-color: black;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <!-- Goal; -->
    <!-- I want a js class that will create itself and manage its own properties
    So when I click on the div I fire up a new object button. -->
    <div>
       <label id = "lblID"></label>
       <div id="div1"></div>
    </div>
    <script>
    document.getElementById("div1").addEventListener("click", createchild, false);
    function createchild(e)
    {
  obj1 = new child(this,e);
 }
 function child(el,e)
 {
  this.parent = el;
  this.parentID = el.id;
  // Create the object
  this.child = document.createElement('div');
  this.parent.appendChild(this.child);
  // Set some attributes
  var c = this.parent.childElementCount + 1;
  this.child.id = "child"+c;
  // Set some style
  var l = e.clientX - 20;
  var t = e.clientY - 20;
  var stylestring = "position:absolute;top:"+t+"px;left:"+l+"px;height:40px;width:40px;background-color:red;";
  this.child.style.cssText = stylestring;
  // Add some eventhandling
  this.child.addEventListener("click",getchildcoords,false);
 }
 function getchildcoords(e)
 {
  alert(this.id);
  e.stopPropagation();
 }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are only setting the position once. If you want the positions to change, you'll either need to use relative values or set the values again (you could do this in the `window.resize()` event).

Comment: Absolute positioning isn't great for responsiveness because it won't automatically update. I would avoid it if you can. If not, you'll have listen to resize events and update its position manually, which can get quite complex

Comment: Be aware when you set the position that the parent element don't might be static, in other words may be absolute or relative. so when you resize the window the element work accordingly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- There is a missing 'i' in 'position' keyword of #div1 css
- Append new divs to the container itself to link their positions
- Use offsetX, offsetY for correct placement

```html
<html>
    <head>
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="1.css"> -->
    <script language="javascript"></script>
    <style>
    #div1{
    position:relative;
    margin:auto auto;
    height:400px;
    width:400px;
    background-color: black;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <!-- Goal; -->
    <!-- I want a js class that will create itself and manage its own properties
    So when I click on the div I fire up a new object button. -->
    <div>
       <label id = "lblID"></label>
       <div id="div1"></div>
    </div>
    <script>
    document.getElementById("div1").addEventListener("click", createchild, false);
    function createchild(e)
    {
  obj1 = new child(this,e);
 }
 function child(el,e)
 {
  this.parent = el;
  this.parentID = el.id;
  // Create the object
  this.child = document.createElement('div');
  
  // Set some attributes
  var c = this.parent.childElementCount + 1;
  this.child.id = "child"+c;
  // Set some style
  var l = e.offsetX - 20;
  var t = e.offsetY - 20;
  var stylestring = "position:absolute;top:"+t+"px;left:"+l+"px;height:40px;width:40px;background-color:red;";
  this.child.style.cssText = stylestring;
      el.appendChild(this.child);
  // Add some eventhandling
  this.child.addEventListener("click",getchildcoords,false);
 }
 function getchildcoords(e)
 {
  alert(this.id);
  e.stopPropagation();
 }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you, could your expound on 'linking their positions'. And, I will try the offsets. I guess I headed down the wrong path googling mouse events and positions.

Comment: Oh, I think I see. But correct me. The parent is a singleton? So there should be no instance to append the children to? And I noticed you appended it after all attributes were set. but before the event handler.

Comment: And one more question. I used notepad. Would you recommend a good studio, maybe one that can catch my horrible typing and spelling issues. Maybe like intelisense in VS.

Comment: Stay away notepad. I use vim and idea. I suggest Idea which is easier to start and it has great features on code assistance / formatting.